# Java: How to check if MongoDB is connected using Junit

Tags: java, mongodb, junit

I am using MongoDB(Version 3.6) in Standalone Java Application. I am struggling to write a JUnit Test to check if I am connected to MongoDB.

Here is how I connect to MongoDB:

```
public MongoCollection<Document> connectToMongoDB(){
        String mongoDBHost = properties.getProperty("mongo.host");
        String port = properties.getProperty("mongo.port");
        int mongoDBPort = Integer.parseInt(port);
        String mongoDatabase = properties.getProperty("mongo.database");
        String mongoCollection = properties.getProperty("mongo.collection");
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoDBHost, mongoDBPort);
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoDatabase);
        MongoCollection<Document> doc = db.getCollection(mongoCollection);
        return doc;

    }
```

What should I return in my method? I coudn't find anything online on how should I check the connection using Junit in MongoDB driver 3? Any help is appreciated

Comment: You don't test db connection in unit test. You mock the connection.

Comment: You mean just return MongoClient and check?

Comment: No. For ex:  You have  method under test say x making call  to connectToMongo method you mock all the calls to mongo in your case mock mongo client, mongo database and mongo collection using mockito libraries. You will only need live connection if you are writing integration tests.